# Error in syntax for nested Select Case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please correct my syntax for nested Select Case When.

```
Update T
set P= a.Quantity
from
(
    select 
    case when D.P> T.Open
    then D.P

    from DOP D 
    inner join T
    on 
    D.PON = T.PON
)a
```

I am new to sql server, so not sure how to write proper select case.

Comment: Please explain the desired logic. It is not easy to infer the correct logic from an obviously not working one!

Comment: `case when ... then ... when ... then ... else ... end`. Where the `else` part is optional.

Comment: "End" keyword is missing

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes If incoming data (POQty) is greater than replace it with current table data, if it is smaller, then it should enter inner case where it is compared with other column data(AlreadyAlloted)

Comment: Both paths of your proposed case state statement result in the value `D.POQty` being used. Why do you even need the case statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to mention:

- You are missing the `END` to finish the `CASE` statement.
- Your subquery is missing a the column alias, so `a.Quantity` can't be recognized properly.
- Make sure that the table you are updating is actually being referenced (the `T` in `UPDATE T SET` might be an alias or the actual table, I wouldn't know without knowing your tables).
- Make sure that each row of the table to be updated is correcly linked to the value to update.

So replace this:

```
Update T
set P= a.Quantity
from
(
    select 
    case when D.P> T.Open
    then D.P

    from DOP D 
    inner join T
    on 
    D.PON = T.PON
)a
```

with something like the following:

```
Update TAlias set 
    P = a.Quantity
from
    T AS TAlias -- Correctly reference table to update
    INNER JOIN
    (
        select 
            T.PON,
            case when D.P> T.Open then D.P END AS Quantity -- Give column alias
        from 
            DOP D 
            inner join T on D.PON = T.PON
    ) AS A 
        ON TAlias.PON = A.PON -- Link table to update to the values to update
```

Although I believe it can be optimized like the following:

```
UPDATE TAlias SET
    P = CASE WHEN D.P > TAlias.Open THEN D.P END
FROM
    T AS TAlias
    INNER JOIN DOP AS D ON TAlias.PON = D.PON
```

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` statement is like a `switch` statement in languages like C#. Basically it's a compound structure for doing a bunch of `if/else` stuff in line. As was mentioned in one of the comments, usually it takes the form of `case when <first condition> then <result on first condition> when <nth condition> then <result of nth condition> <optional else clause> end`. Note the optional `else` clause. If omitted, any values which didn't meet one of the criteria will be set null.

From your example, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to get at here; both paths you've laid out end up mapping to `D.POQty`, and a case statement is really only useful if it maps to *different* values. If all you want is the null  behavior, so be it. But you probably don't need a case statement, or at least not one of this complexity.

That said, in an effort to show how you'd refactor your code to make the statement run, here's what I came up with. I removed your subquery because  you can update a column directly from a case statement. I also combined the compound case statement you had because I didn't see what it added that simply `AND`ing the two conditions together wouldn't. If I didn't get at what you were asking, let me know.

```
update t2s -- References which aliased table you intend to update
set POQty = case when D.POQty > [Tab-2 sourcing].OpenQuantity 
                 then D.POQty 
                 when D.POQty < [Tab-2 sourcing].OpenQuantity and D.POQty > [Tab-2 sourcing].AlreadyAlloted
                 then D.POQty
                 else null -- This is implied if you leave it off. Just adding it in so that its behavior is clear
            end
from DemandPortal D 
inner join [Tab-2 sourcing] t2s
    on D.PONumber = t2s.PONumber
```

CASE statement documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

I think that the case statement is not necessary. You can do all the checks within a where clause:

```
UPDATE T
    SET POQty = D.POQty
FROM
    [Tab-2 sourcing] T
    INNER JOIN DemandPortal D
        ON T.PONumber = D.PONumber
WHERE
    D.POQty > T.OpenQuantity OR
    (D.POQty < T.OpenQuantity AND D.POQty > T.AlreadyAlloted)
```